# How can I stop post method to run by default in Django class based view

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I've noticed that both the `GET` method and the `POST` method in running. I wanted to run only the `GET` method when I'm not performing any `POST` request to that URL.

```
Class Profile(View):
    template_name = 'profile.html'
    def get(self, request):
        # some code...
        return render(request, self.template_name, context_dict)

    def post(self, request):
        # some code...
        return render(request, self.template_name, context_dict)
```

I don't want to run the `POST` method if I'm not performing any `POST` request.
I'm new to django. So sorry if it is a dumb question.

Comment: How do you *use* the `Profile` view?

Comment: It show's the profile information, also a profile edit form to the side. I do a `print` inside of both methods and both are printed. So I guess both methods are getting called.

Comment: how do you bind this to the `urlpatterns`? How do you make requests to the view?

Comment: `urlpatterns = [path('/profile', Profile.as_view(), name='profile')],`

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is to look for the HttpRequest.method, then run the relevant code:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    do_something()
elif request.method == 'POST':
    do_something_else()
```

You can find more info about this here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/

Comment: He's already using the View class with get() and post(), I don't think your answer is relevant to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `HttpResponseNotAllowed` from `django.http`
and disable the post method by:
Include any other method allowed in the list.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponseNotAllowed(["GET", "PUT", "DELETE"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use http decorator to block some methods like this

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

    @require_http_methods(["GET", "POST"])
    def my_view(request):
        pass
```

Read more about decorators here

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/decorators/